# Ajax load more from PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

**Updated:**

I want to make a load more ajax button, I want it to load data from a php file which will extract data from database.

I've managed to make it to load just once, however when I click the new more button it doesn't work.

**Here's the Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".more").click(function(){
        var ID = $(this).attr("id");
        if(ID) {
            $("#more"+ID).html('<img src="moreajax.gif" />');

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "more.php",
                data: "lastimg="+ ID,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    $("div#updates").append(html);
                    $("#more"+ID).remove(); // removing old more button
                }
            });
        } else {
            $(".morebox").html('The End');// no results
        }

        return false;
    });
});
```

**And here's more.php**

```
$lastimg = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastimg']);

$result = $mmhclass->db->query("SELECT * FROM `file_storage` WHERE `is_private` = '0' AND `file_id` < '$lastimg' ORDER BY `file_id` DESC LIMIT 10;", array(MYSQL_FILE_STORAGE_TABLE));

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$file_id = $row['file_id'];
$filename = $row['filename'];
?>
    <li>
        <?php echo $filename; ?>
    </li>
<?php
}
?>
<div id="more<?php echo $file_id; ?>" class="morebox">
    <a href="#" class="more" id="<?php echo $file_id; ?>">more</a>
</div>
```

Comment: And asking an actual question would help as well. Currently you only gave us two copied code samples with no particular question!

Comment: @xXx these are not just 2 copied codes, I wrote most of it, like I said it's based on a tutorial it doesn't mean I copied everything and came to stackoverflow.

Comment: the `more.php` is a mess!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Okay, I worked on it more, it has been updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just work once, because after your ajax completed, the `.more` element will be new on the page,
so the `click` event handler you attach to it, isn't working anymore.

You must use event delegation:

```
$('body').on('click', '.more', function () {
    // your code
});
```

- Note: `jQuery 1.7+` required.

---

References:

- [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) - jQuery API Documentation

Answer (score 0):

I think you may use jQuery [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function

```
$(".more").live("click", function(){ 

// Code here
});
```

Comment: live function is not working in new jQuery, has been replaced with on()

Comment: `.live` method is deprecated in version `1.7` and removed in version `1.9`. Use `on` instead :)